# How to import from a python package which is in a sibling directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and i am having some issues with packages and imports.

My structure is as follows:

```
src/
    base/
        packcore/
            __init__.py
            utils/
                __init__.py
                util_1.py
                util_2.py
            helpers/
                __init__.py
                helper_1.py
                helper_2.py
    some_script.py
    app.py
```

`packcore` is an external package that has been installed using `pip` and put into the `--target=base`.

some of the `helpers` in the `packcore` uses some of the `utils`.

From `app.py` i want to be able to import a `helper`/`util`.

But when i use `from base.packcore.utils import some_util` i get an error saying that no module named `packcore` from inside the `helper/util`

and if i do `from packcore.utils import some_util` i get an error no module named packcore`from the`app.py`

help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `__init__.py` to `base/`, you can make it a Python package to import from. You also need to make the parent a package (Which is currently called `src`) so it is actually a sibling module, rather than many isolated modules.

From there, you can either do an absolute import from the main package:

```
from src.base.packcore.helpers import helper_1
```

Or relative (Assuming you are in `some_script.py` or `app.py`):

```
from .base.packcore.helpers import helper_1
```